# Unfocus an input of a form after pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an input field and I want to disable automatic submit and unfocus the field after pressing `Enter`.

**Code**

```
<input type="search" id="keyword" placeholder="Search..." name="keyword"
       onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){return false; $('#keyword').blur();}"
       autocomplete="off" />
```

The form does not get submitted nor unfocused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `onkeydown="event.keyCode===13 && this.blur();"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from function before `blur` is triggered. You need to call blur first, and then return from function. Please see corrected snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="keyword" placeholder="Search..." name="keyword" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){ $('#keyword').blur(); return false;}" autocomplete="off">
```